# MySQL LEFT JOIN not returning the desired results

Tags: mysql

I have what I think is a simple MySQL issue that I cannot seem to find an answer that applies to what I am doing. I have two tables with a LEFT JOIN. For this example, table 1 will only have 1 row and table 2 will have 3 rows.

TABLE 1: inv_info

```
id  manufacturer    model   description     quantity
1   SP              A55     USB disk        7
```

TABLE 2: inv_category

```
id  categories
1   USB
1   Hard disk
1   SSD
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT manufacturer, model, description, quantity, categories 
FROM inv_info 
LEFT JOIN inv_category ON inv_info.id=inv_category.id 
WHERE manufacturer LIKE '%usb%' 
   OR model LIKE '%usb%' 
   OR description LIKE '%usb%' 
   OR categories LIKE '%usb%'
```

If my search item is one of the category names, it returns results for each category item, not just the one I searched for. I want it to search all the category rows for this search term, but not return a row for each row in inv_categories.

The results I get from the above query:

```
manufacturer    model   description     quantity    categories
SP              A55     USB disk        7           SATA
SP              A55     USB disk        7           SSD
SP              A55     USB disk        7           usb
```

I want it to search both tables, but only return 1 row being data from  table 1, not a row of data for each category in table 2.

Desired result:

```
manufacturer    model   description quantity    categories
SP              A55     USB disk    7           usb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT manufacturer, model, description, quantity, categories 
FROM inv_info 
LEFT JOIN inv_category ON inv_info.id=inv_category.id 
WHERE (    manufacturer LIKE '%usb%' 
        OR model LIKE '%usb%' 
        OR description LIKE '%usb%' )
  AND categories LIKE '%usb%'
```

---

**UPDATE**

This query text implicitly converts LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN due to the condition by the column from `inv_category` table in WHERE clause.

So correct query text is

```
SELECT manufacturer, model, description, quantity, categories 
FROM inv_info 
LEFT JOIN inv_category ON inv_info.id=inv_category.id AND categories LIKE '%usb%'
WHERE (    manufacturer LIKE '%usb%' 
        OR model LIKE '%usb%' 
        OR description LIKE '%usb%' )
```

or maybe even

```
SELECT manufacturer, model, description, quantity, categories 
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM inv_info 
       WHERE (    manufacturer LIKE '%usb%' 
               OR model LIKE '%usb%' 
               OR description LIKE '%usb%' ) ) models
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM inv_category 
            WHERE categories LIKE '%usb%' ) categories USING (id)
```

Comment: This is an inner join

Comment: @Strawberry This is true. Updated.

Comment: So I thought it was good, but... The first answer limits the results like I wanted, but if your search does not contain one of the categories from table 2, it does not give any results. I did not want table 2 to be required. As for the edited version, it gets zero results if my search word is one the categories like "usb".

Comment: @rerat Your task is described partially, so it is difficult to come up with all additional conditions which are not listed. One more variant added.

Comment: Using the logical operators OR & AND along with the parenthesis as you did in the above code helped me enough to get it working. Thank you.